# Spark store kafka offset checkpoint in non-streaming(batch read write) approach

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a use case where I want to process particular set of offset from kafka and store in cassandra and also maintain the checkpoint so that in case of failure, I can restart the application from checkpoint. Since it is not a streaming application -

```
val startingOffsets = """{"topic_name": { "0": 33190, "1": 557900, "2": -2} }"""
val endingOffsets =  """{"topic_name": { "0": 33495, "1": 559905, "2": -1} }"""

val df = sparkSession
        .read
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka.brokers".getConfigValue) 
        .option("subscribe", "kafka.devicelocationdatatopic".getConfigValue) 
        .option("startingOffsets", "kafka.startingOffsets".getConfigValue)
        .option("endingOffsets", "kafka.endingOffsets".getConfigValue)
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") // any failure regarding data loss in topic or else, not supposed to fail, it has to continue...
        .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "3") // any change please remove the checkpoint folder
        .load()
```

And write method is -

```
df
.write
.cassandraFormat(
"tbl_name",
"cassandra.keyspace".getConfigValue,
"cassandra.clustername".getConfigValue )
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDirectory)
.save()
```

I tried this option is not working-

```
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDirectory)
```

On checking I found some blogs which to create checkpoint dir as -

```
 sc.setCheckpointDir("/batchProcessKafka")
```

& writing keep setting as -

```
df.checkpoint(true)
```

But this saves the entire RDD whereas I just want to keep a track of my kafka offset. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What does `.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDirectory)` write into checkpointDirectory?

Comment: It is not working at all. In case of streaming like writestream , it used to work like a charm. My kafka offsets were getting saved and work properly, but with batch query I'am not able to maintain the offset with this option. I don't know why

Comment: oh you're trying to recover if you've not processed information with spark streaming? Yes checkpoint doesn't work. You should rely on kafka for that in spark streaming.

Comment: Also, in your code, shouldn't it be like `ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)`? In our use case we rely on Kafka and/or DB system for managing offsets.

Comment: Hi Piyush , Does my code look like a streaming example ? May be there is some lag in my explaining . So, actually its not streaming application. Its a batch processing where I have particular offset range only to process and not the regular streaming, Therefore, I domt think we need ssc in this case which is nothing but a streaming context & just to be extra sure we want to save the offset in HDFS, anyways even if i rely as per your appraoch. Whenever I start application , it starts consuming from start offset.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I have never tried spark processing without streaming with Kafka. but can you show me how you tried to manage with kafka?

Comment: I grilled alot and seen that sc.setCheckpointDir("/batchProcessKafka") is creating the checkpoint but not picking every time we start the application so I have done a work around and manually saving the offsets in hash and using it in batches each iteration. May be not good solution but the only thing i got as of now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps now. I was looking for a similar way for Kafka and figured spark has an option to trigger the stream just once which kind of runs like a batch and let spark manage the checkpoint/offsets for you.
Here's a PySpark sample -

`df.writeStream.trigger(once=True).format("parquet").option("checkpointLocation", <your checkpoint location>).foreachBatch(<your func here>)`

For more information -
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers